# how can I know this javascript coding flaw from browser as nothing shows up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

html is :

```
<input type='button' value='AddAAAA' id='tagbutton' onclick='add_tag_my();' />
```

javascript snippet:

```
function get_the_script(){
    alert("function get_the_script");

    $.getScript("js/global.js",function(){
        alert("script loaded");

        //addtag(); 

        alert("after getscript");
    });
}


function add_tag_my(){
    alert("i am add_tag_my()");
    get_the_script();
}
```

global.js contains:

```
golabl_var=12;
alert("new_selection =" + new_selection);
```

No declaration exists for the js variable new_selection , so when I run the script, i get output up to the code line :    `alert("function get_the_script");` No code output hence forward( 2 more alerts don't show up). But if i change the mentioned line in `global.js` into     `alert("new_selection");` I get the output of the 2 alert boxes as well.

My question is when I use the code mentioned first for global.js , I don't see any message in chrome console tab, so how can I know that that is the place where my prob resides?

Comment: b4 now, just thought it to be an online editor like the one www.w3schools.com has. But jsfiddle should have highlighted about them well on the homepage

Comment: Is the question "why don't errors in scripts loaded with $.getScript show up in chrome's error console?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use some older versions of jQuery you will get this error in console.
But in new versions the execution of dynamically loaded Javascript ( using `eval` function ) is inside a `try..catch` block ( **line 7371** ). jQuery catches the exception so no error will be shown in console. But you can add error handlers for jQuery ajax function and receive the exception inside the function.

Either you can add a global ajax error handler like this

```
$("div.error").ajaxError(function (e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
     if (settings.dataType == 'script') {
         $(this).html(exception);
     }
});

function get_the_script() {
     alert("function get_the_script");

     $.getScript("js/global.js", function () {
         alert("script loaded");

         //addtag(); 
         alert("after getscript");
     });
}
```

Or you can use `ajax` function with error handlers instead of `getScript`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "js/global.js",
    dataType: "script",
    success: function (data) {
         alert("script loaded");

         //addtag(); 
         alert("after getscript");

    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

If you don't want to add any error handlers, but just want to identify the errors while developing , you can use the options " **Don't pause on Exceptions** ", " **Pause on all Exceptions** ", " **Pause on uncaught Exceptions** " by toggling the pause button at the bottom of Chrome web inspector in **Scripts** mode.